# Не прибавляется + 1

Tags: php

```
$file = file_get_contents('counts.txt');
$file_explode = explode('|', $file);
$file_page = $file_explode[0];
$file_ent = $file_explode[1];
```

В $file_page находится 1. При действии:

```
$file_page *1 + 1
```

ничего не складывает и также возвращает 1. В чём проблема?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А вы где такое видели?

Вообще если вы хотите просто увеличить значение переменной $file_page на единичку то это можно сделать так **$file_page++;**

Если прибавить некое число N то **$file_page += N;**

А вот **$file_page *1 + 1** лично я впервые вижу, я что-то упустил? )))

Comment: я вот догадываю он хотел так `$file_page *= 1 + 1

Answer (score 2):

```
$file = file_get_contents('counts.txt');
$file_explode = explode('|', $file);
$file_page = $file_explode[0]+1;
$file_ent = $file_explode[1];
```

Так не работает? Это весь код?

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант,

```
$file = file_get_contents('counts.txt');
$file_explode = explode('|', $file);
$file_page = intval($file_explode[0])+1;
$file_ent = $file_explode[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

По логике надо юзать операторы явного приведения, хоть есть и автоконверсия, чтобы не задавать такие вопросы.

```
((int)$file_page)++;
```